# How to concatenate NULL as part of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have to get data from it in JSON format. I am using a concatenation method as shown below. The following code replaces a NULL value with an empty string. Instead, I would like to have it as NULL.

```
+ ',"OrderDate":"' + CASE WHEN orderDate IS NULL THEN 
 '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(23), orderDate, 20) END + '"}'
```

The output when orderDate is null is: "OrderDate":"". Instead, I would like to have it as "OrderDate":NULL. I have tried,

```
+ ',"OrderDate":' + CASE WHEN orderDate IS NULL THEN 
 NULL ELSE CONVERT(varchar(23), orderDate, 20) END + '}'
```

I have also tried,

```
+ ',"OrderDate":' + CAST(CASE WHEN orderDate IS NULL 
THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(varchar(23), orderDate, 20) END AS 
VARCHAR) + '}'
```

But the JSON itself came out as NULL. The code snippet I have mentioned above is part of a larger JSON creating SQL code.

Comment: `CASE WHEN orderDate IS NULL THEN 'NULL' else CONVERT(varchar(23), orderDate, 20) END`

Comment: ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(23), orderDate, 20),'null')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something close to your second version, but tweaked slightly like this:

```
+ ',"OrderDate":' + CASE WHEN orderDate IS NULL THEN 
'null' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(23), orderDate, 20) END + '}'
```

this would make your JSON formatted correctly like this (or the snippet of JSON):

```
{"OrderDate":null}
```

Whenever you are using the JSON object in javascript if you had issues you could always pass the JSON string into the `JSON.parse()` method, which will construct the JavaScript object described by your JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ISNULL in-build function

```
SELECT '"OrderDate": '+ ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(23), OrderDate, 20), 'NULL') FROM DateTable
```

Also, SQL Server provides the way to generate JSON format result.
Please check this link [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Copy and paste the following query and execute it

```
-- Create Temp table
CREATE TABLE #TempDateTable (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), OrderDate DATETIME)

--Insert some value to test
INSERT INTO #TempDateTable VALUES('04/24/2019'), (NULL), ('03/24/2019')

-- Generate JSON format result
SELECT ID, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(23), OrderDate, 20), 'NULL') OrderDate
FROM #TempDateTable  
FOR JSON AUTO  

-- Drop the table
DROP TABLE #TempDateTable
```